# How to understand the C# type?

Tags: c#, xml, code-generation

I wrote a code in python that reads a XML data model contains user defined types and user class definitions then converts in to C# class.

for example user creates this XML file:

```
<app:list name="myList" itemType="strering">
    <app:restriction combination="any">
            <app:minSize>1</app:minSize>
     </app:restriction>
</app:list>
```

and my application will converts it to below C# code:

```
private  System.Collections.Generic.List<strering> _myList;
public System.Collections.Generic.List<strering> myList {
get{ return _myList; }
set{
    if (_myList == value)
        return;
    if ((value.Count>=1) || false){
        _myList=value;
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Inserted value for myList is not valid!");
    }

    RaisePropertyChanged ("myList"); // for binding to mvvm model
    }
}
```

if **strering** is defined in XML file so my application can find it in the symbol table and passed it to another level, but my question is How can I understand that user entered list type is .Net built-in type or not?

Comment: For as far as i know it doesn't look like a standard .NET type but i could be wrong have you tried changing all to string ? it looks more like a Miss Typo if you want to know the type of an object you can always use `typeof(MyObject)` or `myObject.GetType().ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's code generation, use a second pass over the XML to know if there are complex types that have been read in the first pass. That's generally how code generators work.

By just looking at the value, there's really no unambiguous way to decide the try.
What I mean to say is that "stering" could be a string or an enumeration. So, you would have to add some logic to decide what should be generated.

Comment: I can compile generated CS code and try to know how it compiled, with error or not, but I want to know how to find that the user entered a correct type or not?

Comment: In the first pass, just scan through the file for all types. This is called lexical analysis. And after your done with that, go through the file once again and check for invalid/unknown types then. The second phase is called semantic checking. Read about how compilers work in general. It will help you a lot with what you seem to be doing.

Comment: My program is not a compiler or interpreter, It is just a translator

Comment: User can define data types as .Net type names,My application just translates xml data model to C# data model

Comment: Where are the types defined? In the XML or elsewhere like in different assembly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14128/discussion-between-pooya-and-akhil-w)

Comment: @Pooya are you saying youre worried that the user could have given any type not necessarily an allowed type? also is this XML generated by your application at some point to be saved then youre re-entering it into the application later? like saving a word document then reopening it. or is this XML coming from random sources that you have no control over?